# When does `QKeySequence::match()` return `QKeySequence::PartialMatch`?

Tags: qt

What sequences partially match?

I thought `1` partially matches `Ctrl+1`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9db7cc79a26ced4997277b5c206ca15949133240/src/gui/kernel/qkeysequence.cpp#L1378),

```
QKeySequence::SequenceMatch QKeySequence::matches(const QKeySequence &seq) const {
    uint userN = count(),
          seqN = seq.count();

    if (userN > seqN)
        return NoMatch;

    // If equal in length, we have a potential ExactMatch sequence,
    // else we already know it can only be partial.
    SequenceMatch match = (userN == seqN ? ExactMatch : PartialMatch);

    for (uint i = 0; i < userN; ++i) {
        QKeyCombination userKey = (*this)[i],
                    sequenceKey = seq[i];
        if (userKey != sequenceKey)
            return NoMatch;
    }
    return match;
}
```

It seems that,

1. The compared sequence has to be longer than the source
2. The compared sequence has to start with the source

So if you have,

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeySequence>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QKeySequence ks_1{Qt::CTRL, Qt::Key_X, Qt::Key_Y};

    QKeySequence ks_2{Qt::CTRL};
    QKeySequence ks_3{Qt::CTRL, Qt::Key_X};
    QKeySequence ks_4{Qt::CTRL, Qt::Key_X, Qt::Key_Y};
    QKeySequence ks_5{Qt::CTRL, Qt::Key_X, Qt::Key_Y, Qt::Key_Z};
    qDebug() << ks_1.count() << ks_2.count() << ks_1.matches(ks_2);
    qDebug() << ks_1.count() << ks_3.count() << ks_1.matches(ks_3);
    qDebug() << ks_1.count() << ks_4.count() << ks_1.matches(ks_4);
    qDebug() << ks_1.count() << ks_5.count() << ks_1.matches(ks_5);

    return a.exec();
}
```

`ks_4` would be an exact match, and `ks_5` would be a partial match.
Note that the length is acquired using `count()`, which from the source is:

```
int QKeySequence::count() const
{
    return int(std::distance(d->key, std::find(d->key, d->key + QKeySequencePrivate::MaxKeyCount, 0)));
}
```

So if the previous example is declared as:

```
QKeySequence ks_1{Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X + Qt::Key_Y};

QKeySequence ks_2{Qt::CTRL};
QKeySequence ks_3{Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X};
QKeySequence ks_4{Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X + Qt::Key_Y};
QKeySequence ks_5{Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X + Qt::Key_Y + Qt::Key_Z};
```

All will be no match, since `count()` returns 1 for all cases above.